# Anyone figure out how to save a JSON string into a DocumentDB collection?

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb

Am trying to make a quick and dirty NLog DocumentDB target but can't seem to be able to directly save JSON into a DocumentDB.

Using the C# library seems the document parameter of *DocumentClient.CreateDocumentAsync()* only wants a 'complex type' and I see no other methods that might take a JSON string.

Anybody else figured out how to save JSON directly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a sample of how you can save a JSON string using DocumentDB using the C# SDK.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"{ a : 5, b: 6, c: 7 }"))) 
{
    await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionSelfLink,
        Document.LoadFrom<Document>(ms));
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about streaming it.

Comment: I tried the above solution, It works for the simple objects but doesn't work for the complex objects. Is there any other way to do the same for complex objects?